# Convert JS array exactly to string

Tags: javascript

How can I print a JS array (`["a", "b", "c"]`) exactly to a string.

When I do `["a", "b", "c"].toString()` I will get `'a,b,c'`

I want the string: `["a", "b", "c"]`

There is probably a neat method but I can't think of one.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.stringify([...])`?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, including using `join`, `array + ""` etc

Comment: Also: `'["' + input.join('", "') + '"]'`

Answer (score 0):

If `["a","b","c"]` is good enough, you could simply use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
const str = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(str);
```